# Customise new.aspx for creation of custom document library

Tags: 2010, development, document-library

I have created a new document library template in CAML using the Visual Studio template. I have only made a couple of changes and these are all in the Elements.xml (e.g. to change the title, id etc. I have various customisations that i apply using a list created event reciever that checks the template id and only performs customisations on my library.

My problem is that my event reciever sets the versioning settings and document template, so i don't want these options to appear when the list is created from the front-end (as they'll be overwritten).

Is there any way of customising new.aspx or even better, is there something in my library definition that i can change to control what options are displayed when the library is created.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood completely what you're trying to achieve:

- If you are refering to the way (screen) a list gets created by
  End-User you have few options - you could on the other hand create
  your own form which reads minimal parameters and creates the list
  programatically, so you avoid that alltogether.
- You could have a SPListEventReceiver for your sub-Site that would handle (and Ignore) user's selection acting upon ListAdding/-Added and do your own processing.
- Or if your interest is more about how the form for NEW ITEM behaves, that is controllable by your list Schema.xml and the Field definitions, where you get to specify which fields are visible on the NEW Form (e.g. ShowInNewForm="FALSE" - to hide a field)

Hope this covers it,
C:\Marius

Comment: Hi Marius. Thanks it was the first of your points that i have been trying to achieve, i have started using the approach in your second point which seems fine, bit of a shame i can't use the exiting create framework though.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

VersioningEnabled="FALSE" on your list.

here is the full xml schema of what you can use
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439434.aspx